# Multi Store Cookie Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, session, cookie, multidomain

We have two stores in our Magento 1.9 installation: a retail website, `coolstuff.com` (no www prefix) and a wholesale website, `dealer.coolstuff.com`. Following the launch of our website with HTTPS forced on for all pages, we are having issues only on the wholesale website (i.e., subdomain `dealer.coolstuff.com`) that are seemingly session/cookie related based on what I've found researching.

It seems as though most topics on this subject desire the customer's session to be persisted across both stores (e.g., regional stores, such as `north.mysite.com` and `south.mysite.com`). This **is not our desired functionality**-- we run two separate stores with separate customer bases and separate pricing, so therefore you should be able to be logged into `coolstuff.com` with one account, and `dealer.coolstuff.com` with a different account.

My system configuration under 'General -> Web -> Session Cookie Management" is as follows:

**Scope:** coolstuff.com

```
Cookie Path: /
Cookie Domain: coolstuff.com
```

**Scope:** dealer.coolstuff.com

```
Cookie Path: /
Cookie Domain: dealer.coolstuff.com
```

I'm noticing in my Chrome Resource Management that I have a `frontend` cookie for both domains **with the same session id** and the `Domain` is prefixed with a `.` e.g., `.coolstuff.com` and `.dealer.coolstuff.com` both have a value of `tfbjsnm5df2o2hqcofbh9r3s74` but **different expiration dates**. This seems like a configuration issue, but I just can't seem to get it figured out.

What am I doing wrong here? I feel like the issue is that the browser isn't sure which cookie to use? Would a `www` prefix on our retail website (and corresponding change to cookie configuration) resolve this? I'm really scratching my head here, any input would be great!!

Comment: I am having the same issue with setting up a staging area for my website. I changed the production (main) version's cookie url to "www.DOMAIN.com" and the staging version to "staging.DOMAIN.com"

It seems like something is looking to the FQDN (www version) even if you navigate to the subdomain first.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you're creating a cookie that doesn't have an explicit sub-domain. Adding the www subdomain to coolstuff.com and clearing your cookies should fix the issue.

When you visit dealer.coolstuff.com it's sending along the cookies for coolstuff.com, loading the same session id and then generating a 2nd cookie for dealer.coolstuff.com